# Parent directive transclusion does not work when content generated by child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives where the outer one is using transclusion.  It should be attaching an attr to content that is inside the outer directive that is being generated by the inner directive however the attach attr does not seem to work:

[plunker link 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGgbBcBB3TRYutango8H?p=preview)

I am also getting the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`

Which I assume has something to do with this.

If I don't use the inner directive and manually place the html in the outer directive that would be generated by the inner directive, everything works fine:

[plunker link 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/jl49JJKkOU4BIHX6M9GN?p=preview)

The actually use case here is that I have two directives.  One of them in a search query component that lets you build a search with specific syntax and validates it as you type letting you know if you have any syntax errors.  I also have a extend text component which one of the features in an auto complete.  Both of these components work fine separately however I am try to combine the functionality so that I can have a query builder with auto complete.  I am running into the issue that none of the functionality of the extend text component is actually being added to the search query component (just like none of the functionality of outer directive is being added to inner directive here).

Is there anything I am doing wrong here (why am I getting that childNodes error)?  Is this not the way to combine functionality of two directives that each have there own templates?

**NOTE**

- This is a base bone code example that is showing the same issue I am having with the real code.  The real code is over 1000 lines long with the extend text and search query components combined so I am not posting that since there is a ton of code that is not related to this specific issue.  While in this example I could just bind the event in javascript, that won't with the real code.  The solution needs to allow me to be able to bind directives in the transclusion process of the outer directive.
- I Have tried `transclude: 'element'` instead of `transclude = true` but when I do that the input does not even show up on the page
- I though about trying to make so I am have both directives on the same element however they both require there own templates so as far as I know I have to have those directives on separate elements

**UPDATE**

Based on @zeroflagL suggestion, I removed the used on $compile however it still does not work

[plunker link 3](http://plnkr.co/edit/nVhTTRfHv47jYfhjVWM3?p=preview)

The input does have the ng-click and there are no more javascript error however clicking the input does not trigger the alert.

Answer (score 0):

`element.find('.outer-inputs').append($compile(copyElement)($scope));`

You don't need `$compile`.

`compile: function(element, attributes, transclude) {`

The use of `transclude` in the compile function is deprecated.

Working example:

```
compile: function(element, attributes) {
          return {
            pre: function($scope, element, attributes) {
            },
            post: function($scope, element, attributes, ctrl, transclude) {
              transclude($scope, function(clone) {
                var copyElement = clone.filter('.outer-copy');

                copyElement.find('input').on('click', function() {
                  focus();
                  //$scope.$apply();  only if you change the model.
                });

                element.find('.outer-inputs').append(copyElement);
              });
```

Not related to the problem: The directive's controller is useless, as it has no methods. You can add `focus()` to the scope directly in your directive.

**Edit**

In your example you compile an element that already has been compiled and is still under construction (the post-link phase). That's not going to work. You effectively try to change your `inner` directive. But either the directives are idependent, then `outer` shouldn't mess with `inner`, or they are aware of each other. In that case there's no need for hacking the DOM as they could interoperate in other ways.

Comment: I added another plunker with your suggestions but still not fully working, could you add a plunker link with it working?

Comment: Also to your other non-related point, I am in the habit I placing non-DOM related functionality for directives in controllers to make that functionality easier to test (can test without mocking HTML and such).

Comment: @ryanzec sorry, I forgot that you are adding an `ng-click` attribute. Maybe that's why you used `$compile`. I think, however, it's overkill here. You can simply add an event listener. I update my answer.

Comment: @ryanzec As for the controller: Good point. However, if something's not DOM (or GUI) related, then a directive is the wrong place for it, anyway ;)

Comment: I updated the NOTE section of the main post but this is just the bare bone code needed to re-produce the issue I am having with the real code.  The real code is over 1000 lines long and I am not going to post that since there is a ton of stuff not related to the issue that this minimal code example shows (I want to focus to be on this issue and not the entire codebase of the components). While it fixes the issue with the bare bone example, that solution does not work with the real code, I need to be able to bind directives in the transclusion process of the outer directive.

Comment: @ryanzec I've updated my answer in response to your notes. Without any further information or a more reality-like example it's not possible to provide a specific solution.